# Cannot properly link the libraries in CMakeLists

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin

I have some troubles with linking the source files (I have added them as Libraries in my CMakeLists) with my main file. Here is my `CMakeLists`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(ros_bridge)

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_CATKIN_COMPONENTS
  nav_msgs
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

add_compile_options(-std=c++14)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_CATKIN_COMPONENTS})
find_package(RapidJSON REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS
    include
    include/aws_iot_sdk
    include/common
    include/network
  CATKIN_DEPENDS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_CATKIN_COMPONENTS}
)


include_directories(
  include
  include/aws_iot_sdk
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Libraries

add_library(ros_client src/ros_client.cpp)
add_library(ConfigCommon include/common/ConfigCommon.cpp)
add_library(OpenSSL include/network/OpenSSL/OpenSSLConnection.cpp)
add_library(WebSocket include/network/WebSocket/WebSocketConnection.cpp)

add_executable(ros_bridge_node src/main.cpp)

## Lib links
target_link_libraries(ros_client ConfigCommon ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${RapidJSON_LIBRARIES} OpenSSL WebSocket)
target_link_libraries(ConfigCommon ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${RapidJSON_LIBRARIES} OpenSSL WebSocket)

target_link_libraries(ros_bridge_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ros_client ConfigCommon OpenSSL WebSocket ${RapidJSON_LIBRARIES})
```

So when the compiler tries to link my main file (which is `ros_bridge_node`) I get the error with the linkage:

```
ros_client.cpp:(.text+0x605): undefined reference to `awsiotsdk::util::Logging::GetLogSystem()'
ros_client.cpp:(.text+0x66d): undefined reference to `awsiotsdk::ResponseHelper::ToString[abi:cxx11](awsiotsdk::ResponseCode)'
CMakeFiles/ros_bridge_node.dir/src/ros_client.cpp.o: In function `ros_bridge::RosClient::RunPublish(int&)':
ros_client.cpp:(.text+0x8d9): undefined reference to `awsiotsdk::Utf8String::Create(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
/home/abyl/master-wheel/devel/lib/libWebSocket.so: undefined reference to `BIO_push'
/home/abyl/master-wheel/devel/lib/libWebSocket.so: undefined reference to `awsiotsdk::NetworkConnection::Read(std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long&)'
/home/abyl/master-wheel/devel/lib/libConfigCommon.so: undefined reference to `awsiotsdk::util::JsonParser::InitializeFromJsonFile(rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/home/abyl/master-wheel/devel/lib/libWebSocket.so: undefined reference to `SHA1'
/home/abyl/master-wheel/devel/lib/libWebSocket.so: undefined reference to `BIO_f_base64'
/home/abyl/master-wheel/devel/lib/libWebSocket.so: undefined reference to `awsiotsdk::network::OpenSSLConnection::IsPhysicalLayerConnected()'
/home/abyl/master-wheel/devel/lib/libWebSocket.so: undefined reference to `BIO_set_flags'
/home/abyl/master-wheel/devel/lib/libWebSocket.so: undefined reference to `BIO_new'
```

So how can I properly link the libraries against my Main file?

EDIT:

I have `set` the object files of `aws_iot_sdk` like this:

```
set(${aws_sdk} /home/ren/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/aws-iot-sdk-cpp.dir/src)


set_source_files_properties(
  ${aws_sdk_path}
  PROPERTIES
  EXTERNAL_OBJECT true
  GENERATED true
)
```

And tried to link that against my main file:

```
target_link_libraries(ros_bridge_node ros_client ConfigCommon Open WebSocket wslay ${RapidJSON_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} -lssl ${aws_sdk})
```

But still getting the same linkage problem. May be I am linking the object files wrong? (Now all the linkage problem is from the `aws_iot_sdk`)

Comment: @Tsyvarev I thought `undefined reference` occurs when you do not link the library?

Comment: Your errors are complaining (mostly) about definitions in `awsiotsdk`. You include this directory but I don't see where you link to the library for it. Is there a `aws_iot_sdk` library? If so, can you try including that when calling `target_link_libraries()`?

Comment: @squareskittles I have edited my question, please have a look

Comment: For assign `aws_sdk` variable use command `set(aws_sdk ...)`, dereferencing `${aws_sdk}` is wrong here. Note also, that in `target_link_libraries` call you need to specify **libraries**. not a *directories* contained them. A linker has no option "link all libraries in that directory".

Comment: As for `undefined reference`, I just found that `/home/abyl/master-wheel/devel/lib/libWebSocket.so` library is actually built in your project, not a 3d-party (pre-created) one. Nevermind about my first comment (currently deleted).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok, I got a bit confused. If I built the libraries in my project, why then I get the linkage error if I link them at the end? Also, if the libraries are outside of my project, you mean I have to get every single `.o` file and link them against my main?

Comment: The things are simple: For every symbol(function) used in the library you build you need to pass to the linker either a an object file or a library which define that symbol.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Can I get all object files into one directory and link them as `"/path/to/objects/*.o`?

Comment: You may collect objects using [file(GLOB)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/file.html#glob).